# Are there any libraries that implement the record data type using a hash table?

Tags: lua

I was curious if there are any libraries/programming languages that implement the [record data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)) using a hash table.  I know there's the [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass) library for Lua that expands on the table data type to implement classes.

Comment: Are you looking for https://luarocks.org/modules/UlisseMini/luastruct